# dump icmplib result in json format

Tags: python, json, utf-8, decode, icmp

I'm trying to dump the output of ping test from icmplib library. How should I convert the output to make it compatible for json.dumps?

```
import json
from icmplib import ping

def pingTest(ipaddress):
    host = ping(ipaddress, count=5, privileged=True, payload_size=56)
    print(type(host)) #<class 'icmplib.models.Host'>
    #print(host, host.is_alive)
    print(json.dumps(host)) #TypeError: Object of type Host is not JSON serializable
pingTest('192.168.255.68')

#This will not work too
outputFinal = host.decode("utf-8") #AttributeError: 'Host' object has no attribute 'decode'
outputFinal = outputFinal.replace("\n","\r\n")
```

Output of the ping test is:

```
  192.168.255.68
------------------------------------------------------------
  Packets sent:     5
  Packets received: 5
  Packet loss:      0.0%
  Round-trip times: 39.309 ms / 45.119 ms / 55.299 ms
  Jitter:           6.866 ms
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you give a example output of the ping test

Comment: sure, I added it to the post

Comment: and you will the text in what format? A string? A dictionary?

Comment: just a big string would be fine

Comment: what is the format you get the text from the ping test?

Comment: #<class 'icmplib.models.Host'

Comment: The [`Host` class](https://github.com/ValentinBELYN/icmplib/blob/main/icmplib/models.py) provides a lot of properties and a formatted `__str__` representation (what you pasted), but it doesn't provide a JSON-serialisable variant of the information. You'll have to construct a dict yourself, like `json.dumps({"packets_sent": host.packets_sent, ...})` – for all the values you're after.